# Securing an API using Azure - How do external people get a client id?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a website hosted in Azure with an API that is secured using JWT tokens generated by Azure.

The application will be accessed by people added as guests to my Azure AD.

Inside Azure under app registrations I have registered a native app (with `availableToOtherTenants` set to true), and when I authenticate to my API I use its application id as my client id and the resource id, and the tennancy as my azure ad tennancy.

This works fine.

Now I would like to add an external user, so I've added them as a guest. Should I be giving them my client id and asking them to just use that, or should they somehow add this application to their Azure AD, and create their own client ids (which I'd have to whitelist in my API application when I'm validating JWT tokens)

Please note they are accessing my API via a native client (console app)

Comment: If you are using Azure-AD for authentication in a 3 legged model then AFAIK you do not need to share any details, the user navigates to the site / API (url) and is redirected to Azure-AD for authentication if a cached token is not available.

Comment: Yep,you don't need to share your clinet id of your AAD Application. If a guest user want to access your API and the user will be redirected to AAD endpoint which with your AAD App.

Comment: How does this work if they are accessing my api from a console application.